# Possibility of changing userId from oneSignal " Android "

Tags: javascript, android, angular, onesignal

I'm working on an Android application that utilizes OneSignal for push notifications. I've encountered a scenario where I need to change the userId associated with the OneSignal player. However, I couldn't find a clear way to achieve this in the OneSignal documentation.

Is there a recommended approach or method provided by OneSignal or any workarounds to change the userId programmatically within an Android application? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.